# Custom hook to add query params always renders the component the using it when the location is changed. Used react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-custom-hooks

**Problem**

I have a custom hook which is used for updating the query string in the url with the help of **location** and **history** from **'react-router-dom'**. So in the components whenever I want to add a new query I use this hook. In this custom hook I used **useRef** to avoid updating the custom hook so that the component using the hook will not render, but components using this hooks are rendered every time the location is changed.

**Custom hook to update query string in the url**

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const useUpdateQueryString = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const location = useLocation()

  const routerRef = useRef({ search: '', pathname: '' })

  useEffect(() => {
    routerRef.current = { pathname: location.pathname || '', search: location.search || '' }
  }, [location.pathname, location.search])

  const onUpdateQueryString = useCallback((newQueryObj) => {
    const newQueryParamString = setQueryStringValue(newQueryObj, routerRef.current.search)
    history.push(`${routerRef.current.pathname}${newQueryParamString}`)
  }, [])

  return {
    onUpdateQueryString
  }
}
```

**Component which uses this hook**

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { getTestQueryObj, useTestQueryString } from 'utils/query-string'


const TestComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { onUpdateQueryString } = useTestQueryString()

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    onUpdateQueryString(getTestQueryObj())
  }, [])

  console.log('TestComponent rendered')
  return <div onClick={handleClick}>{'Hello Component'}</div>
}

export default React.memo(TestComponent)
```

Note: *getQueryObj* is a function which gets the query obj and *setQueryObj* is a another function which takes the query obj and returns a string

Comment: You are changing the `location` though, so the routed components will rerender. What is the question/issue?

Comment: All components using this hook are getting rendered, that should not happen right? because the handlers returning from hook are memoized. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The components are rerendered because the location changed, not because of simply using this `useUpdateQueryString` hook. The `useUpdateQueryString` updates the location, so it will trigger a location change, which rerenders anything in the router.

Comment: Thanks for the repsone @DrewReese, yeah I'm aware that change in location will rerenders everything in the router. But it should not happen when the components inside that route are memoized.
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wilson-h1bbvi?file=/src/Component2.js
If you the code sandbox link, I have two components which is using this hook and when I update the query from one component, the other components also gets rendered.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't happen? Why do you think the components are memoized? `React.memo` only memoizes against the props and is also only used as a hint to React to not rerender, and neither component receives any props. The docs even say not to use `memo` to prevent rerenders. In your sandbox I see two components rendered directly as children of the `HashRouter`. If the location changes, the router rerenders. When a React component rerenders it rerenders its entire subtree, i.e. all its children also rerender.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here I'm not using useLocation from react-router-dom which will render all the components using it, instead I used window location. My components just need a hook to add the query params to the location.
Few components need info about location change so created another hook to watch the location updates.

```
const location = useLocation()
```

```
// Hook
export const useUpdateQueryString = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  const onAddQueryString = (newQueryObj: Record<string, unknown>) => {
    const newLocationWithQueryParams = addQueryToLocation(newQueryObj)
    history.push(`${newLocationWithQueryParams}`)
  }

  return {
    onAddQueryString,
    onDeleteQueryStrings,
  }
}

// Method to add query to the location url
const addQueryToLocation = (value: Record<string, unknown>): string => {
  const location = window.location
  const existingQueryParamString = location.hash.split('?')[1] || ''
  const values = qs.parse(existingQueryParamString, { sort: false })
  const newQsValue = qs.stringify({ ...value, ...values }, { sort: false })
  return `?${newQsValue}`
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mountain-zmv4qn

You can check the link, now only Component 3 is rendered whenever the query params change.